# How do I make my input work inside my function?

Tags: python, function, input

So I should get an input in my function, then return that value and call that return value from an another function, but when I call the fuction it gives this error message: ypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

```
def hello(name):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name == "":
        return hello_world()
    else:
        return ("Hello "+ name)
def print_hello(name):
    print(hello())
hello()
```

If I put the input outside the hello() function get's the same error.

Comment: `hello()` requires a parameter. You are trying to call it without one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `name` argument from the function definition `def hello(name):` since you are requesting it from the user input.

Should be `def hello():`.